# Requesting Data from API Controller using GET with data as complex object

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, controller, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have, until today always used POST to get response from API Controllers in .NETCore/MVC applications, but have been struggling with performance and have noted that POST cannot be cached...

So, I am trying to change things to use a GET request.

**I do not like this, because I would prefer the data sent as a form, not in the URL... but if it must, it must**

Anyway, I am having trouble getting .NET to serialize data posted using an object in the AJAX post (using jQuery or otherwise, I don't care)

My controller looks like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("ProductStockHistory")]
    public async Task< ChartResponse> ProductStockHistory([FromQuery] ChartQuery value)
    {
     //// do stuff
    }
```

You can see I want to send a `ChartQuery` object, this looks like this:

```
    public class ChartQuery
    {
        public string dateFrom { get; set; }
        public string dateTo { get; set; }
        public string groupBy { get; set; } = "month";
        // more values...
    }
```

Using a POST, I would do this: (with the `[HttpGet]` attribute changed to `[HttpPost]` and `[FromQuery]` changed to `[FromBody]`)

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Chart/" + chartAction,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                dateFrom : dateFromValue, 
                dateTo : dateToValue, 
                groupBy : groupByValue, 
                // more values...
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                // do stuff
            }
        });
```

This works fine... but as per my opening statement, I cannot cache a POST request/response.

You can probably tell I am trying to get data for a chart, so it is not changing, therefore a cached response is adequate for me.

I have tried many variations of the AJAX code and the most logical to me looks like this:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Chart/" + chartAction,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { value: JSON.stringify({
                dateFrom : dateFromValue, 
                dateTo : dateToValue, 
                groupBy : groupByValue, 
                // more values...
            })},
            processData: true, 
            success: function (data) {
                // do stuff
            }
        });
```

This is generating a URL like: `/Chart/ProductStockHistory?value=%7B"dateFrom "%3AdateFromValue%2C"dateTo"%3AdateToValue%7D`, which looks about right, but .NET is not serializing the value, I'm getting a null/default object as `value` in my controller.

It's entirely possible that I am approaching it wrong, but how can I get a cached response when using a complex object as a value in a controller?

**EDIT: note, I realise I could change the controller to receive individual values of the `ChartQuery` object, but that is not what I am trying to achieve**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to call `JSON.stringify` on your ajax request. Something like this should work:

```
data:{
 dateFrom : dateFromValue, 
 dateTo : dateToValue, 
 groupBy : groupByValue, 
}
```

This should produce a request url like this:
`/Chart/ProductStockHistory?dateFrom=dateFromValue&dateTo=dateToValue&groupBy=groupByValue`

.net core binds those values then correctly to your `ChartQuery` model.

Comment: Unbelievably simple!! Thanks

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help :D